# How to extract web address up to some levels from URL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my table I have ID, store, url

In url I have two levels of web address

Level 2: www.abc.com/product/coffee/
                        1      2
Level 3: www.abc.com/product/coffee/caffee_name
                        1      2      3
I need to get ( two different queries) Id and store name when url as 
www.abc.com/product/coffee/ or www.abc.com/product/coffee/caffee_name.
What I mean here is, after www.abc.com there would be two or three level
(as I marked above). I need separate two queries for to get Id and Store 
when url as level 2 and level 3. www.abc.com is common for each rows but 
rest of the url path are different. (different pages),( I need to get in 
generic way, those are just examples)

`select url from my_table where url like 'www.abc/product/%/'`

This gave me all the urls available, I need only up to level 2 and level 3

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Comment: iam going to voteclose this question after a code attempt which was no good i requested a MVCE which never came..

Comment: Based on your code I got the correct answer!  What is the meaning of this pls? (LENGTH(url) - LENGTH (REPLACE(url, '/', '')))

Comment: *"Based on your code I got the correct answer! What is the meaning of this pls? (LENGTH(url) - LENGTH (REPLACE(url, '/', ''))) "* great consider to accept the answer.. simply said it calculates how many `/` are in the url string.. Here is visible what [happens](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9d9e68818175a98f878cf7e133822d4c)

Comment: We replace "/" by " " and get the count of "/"? Can't we directly count "/" rather replace?  Why do we replace here?

Comment: "We replace "/" by " "" No the `REPLACE()` in thise case **removes** the `/` it does not make a space.  "Why do we replace here?" to calculate the difference between the URL with / and a URL without / .. i was hoping you would noticed and understand that when you looked into [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9d9e68818175a98f878cf7e133822d4c) example?  *"Can't we directly count "/" rather replace?"* Maybe Oracle database has alot of functions i think this is on off the most easy method of doing this, i could be wrong here

Comment: *"Maybe Oracle database has alot of functions i think this is on off the most easy method of doing this, i could be wrong here "* Well i guess i was wrong Oracle database provides a much more easy way to count it seams `REGEXP_COUNT(url, '/') ` see mine updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This query seams to be working but it is a educated guess as your data might give other results.

```
select 
   url
 , (LENGTH(url) - LENGTH (REPLACE(url, '/', '')))
from urls
where url like 'www.abc.com/product/%'
AND (LENGTH(url) - LENGTH (REPLACE(url, '/', ''))) BETWEEN 3 AND 4
```

see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2dc2a45ef6fb15ad6079ad62d78d6322)

> Can't we directly count "/" rather replace?

I looked some more in the Oracle database documentation for a more easy method. 
In Oracle 11 G Release 2 (11.2)+ you can use

```
   SELECT
       url
     , REGEXP_COUNT(url, '/') 
    FROM urls
    WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(url, '/') BETWEEN 3 AND 4
```

see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=307640d16987412836b58862c980f628)

which is even more simple

Comment: Appreciate your code, but this is not what I need, actually from url column I need to get one result set, where url ='www.abc.com/product/......../' and other one is url ='www.abc.com/product/....../........./, This is what I meant by level 2 and level 3

Comment: *"Appreciate your code, but this is not what I need"* @User1 in that case see mine comment under your question.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I'm expecting, I need not the size.

Comment: Please one quick help, how to add '/' at the end of the url. I tried with concatenate with case, but no correct result

Comment: @User1 you would need to reask a new question as iam on holiday